# evolution: how to change the subject format of forwarded emails

Tags: evolution

By default, when one forwards an email with Evolution, the subject becomes

```
Subject: [Fwd: <Original subject>]
Subject: [Fwd: Answer to your email]
```

How to configure this? How to tell evolution not to use brackets as follows:

```
Subject: Fwd: Answer to your email
```

Comment: any solution to this, the below does not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

The default settings for replying and forwarding can be changed under

Edit ▸ Preferences ▸ Composer Preferences ▸ General ▸ Replies and Forwards ▸ Forward style